# Is it possible to derive a deterministic CSPRNG given two functions, at least one of which is a CSPRNG?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cryptography, randomness, pseudo-random-generators

Let `f` and `g` be two functions with integer range `0..m-1`. They may keep state and interact with the world (for example setting a seed or reading the current time), calling them multiple times may produce different results. `f` and `g` can see each other's state, but cannot modify the other's state.

Assume at least one of `f` and `g` is a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator, but it is unknown which one. Is it possible to create a function `h` that uses `f` and `g` and behaves as a CSPRNG? `h` is not allowed to set or read external state directly, the only way it can modify or read state is by calling `f` and `g` and observing their results. `h` should work for any given `f` and `g`.

Of course, `h` is not allowed to use any "true" source of randomness, and ideally the construction should not involve passing randomness tests.

As a related problem, I believe that if `f` and `g` were perfectly random, then `f + g (mod m)` would also be perfectly random. But I think in this deterministic case, it's always possible to create a `g` such that it "cancels out" `f` in `h`. Not sure how to prove this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  There's no way to create such an $h$.

Here's an informal sketch of the proof.  Suppose $f$ is a CSPRNG.  Then for all $h$, there exists a $g$ such that $h(f,g)$ outputs only even numbers.  In particular, $g$ reads the state of $f$, deduces what $f$'s next output will be, and outputs something that will cause $h$ to output an even number (if necessary, by generating multiple candidate outputs and testing each one to see which will provoke $h$ to output an even number).

[This is the main idea of a proof.  To get a full formal proof, you'd also have to consider the case where $h$ ignores its second input or mostly ignores its second input.  However, it's pretty easy to see that such a $h$ can't possibly be any good, either.]

---

That's the theory.  What about practice?  In the real world, if you're not sure whether $f$ or $g$ are any good, *don't let them read the internal state of anything else*.  Don't ever let something that might be malicious read the internal state of security-critical parts of your system.

---

If you know that $f$ and $g$ are independent (as random variables), and you know that at least one of $f,g$ is a secure CSPRNG, then $f+g \bmod m$ is indeed good (it's a secure CSPRNG).  However, the critical requirement here is that they be *independent*.  If one can read the internal state of the other, then they're not independent.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a more rigorous proof, but I think I need to more clearly define the model of computation first.